# When I try to return the index values of an item in a multidimensional array, I do not get numbers. I get a weird set of characters. Why?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indexing, return

I have this code below that is supposed to return the index values of an item in a multidimensional array. However, when I run it, it gives me back this instead:

```
Found at: [I@7ea987ac

    public static String findWord(char[][]board, String word) {
            for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                    if (board[row][col] == word.charAt(0)) {
                        return "Found at: " + new int[] {row,col};
                    }
                }
            }
            return "Not found.";
        }
```

What is wrong with the code that it is not giving me back the correct index values?

Comment: You're printing the array object, which by default returns the object mem allocation, if you want to print it should be return "Found at: " + row + ", " + col};

Comment: Try printing it using `java/util/Arrays.toString(int[])`. That is, `return "Found at: " + java/util/Arrays.toString(new int[] {row,col});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the default `toString()` from array, you could change this

```
return "Found at: " + new int[] {row,col};
```

to use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) with something like

```
return "Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row,col});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're returning an array as a String, and so you'll get the default `toString()` returned by the array, for you, `[I@7ea987ac`, where the `[I` means an array of int, and the numbers are the array's hashCode.

Solution: don't return an array as a String, but rather extract the string data needed and return that.

Instead return something like:

```
return String.format("Found at [%d, %d]", row, col);
```